# sessionState time out not working

Tags: .net, asp.net, session, iis-7, session-timeout

I've set the sesstionstate time out to be 60 i.e. 1 hour. But, users are still getting session expired messages after 20min.

we are using Windows Server 2008 to host the asp.net application. could anyone please tell me why could session expire in 20min please?

I'm using windows authentication. below is my web config:

```
<sessionState  timeout="60" />
```

Comment: How exactly did you try to set the SessionState timeout? Please post relevant code or explain in more details.

Comment: where did u configure the session timeout? in web.config or iis?

Comment: apologies, i've updated my original question with web.config values.

Comment: Dublicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606167/asp-net-session-time-out

Answer (score 4):

Check the IIS Session amount. It can be vary from the .NET session amount.

[Configure Session Time-out (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820%28WS.10%29.aspx)
See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606167/asp-net-session-time-out)

> By default, the session expires when the user has not requested or refreshed a page in the ASP application for 20 minutes

Comment: the link you provided is only applicable for classic ASP or ASP.NET as well?

Comment: It's no matter for the session on the IIS - ASP and ASP.NET pages can be run in one application. IIS handles session apart of the .NET

Comment: Also check for timeout on forms authentication(if you are using that) and application pool idle time

Comment: hm.. any idea what is Idle-Time Out in seetting of Application Pool Could this be causing an issue as well?

Comment: Did you try changing the IIS Session idle time?

Comment: isn't sessionState   suppose to overwrite the iis timeout configuration?

Comment: @The Poet Yes, you can overwrite the session timeout in web.config

Answer (score 0):

First Check the Windows Event Log to ensure that the Worker Process is not being forced to recycle.
There may be something in your code that causes the Worker Process to force itself to recycle in which case when the session is stored `inProc` it will loose all session values it's holding.
[image]

You need to make these changes in the IIS=>Pool Application=>Advance Setting...

[image]
[image]
[image]