# ASP.NET timeout not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout

why isn't my timeout attribute working. I set it to 1 minute, even then It has been more than an hour and the session hasn't expired. Here is what i have written in web.config

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="1" cookieless="UseCookies"  />
    </authentication>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" />
  </system.web>
```

any help?

Comment: You might have to set it in the IIS as well. Check if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6249444/1787888

Comment: I have set the time out in Application Pools in IIS.. but to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just inherited a project with with the same issue. One possibility is to make sure your pages aren't making any calls to the server and resetting the timeout. You can try using something like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see if your app is sending *Get* requests...

I had Ajax Timer Controls refreshing updatePanels as the source of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are using cookies so its not expiring time its save your session live in cookies